# Images not appear in Camera Roll, using elcimagepickercontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, elcimagepickercontroller

I used `elcimagepickercontroller` in my app, when want to choose images from Gallery images not appear but when select it it appear kindly check the attachment images. [image: Select from Gallery]

[image: No Images]
but when [image: clicked] 
How to appear my gallery photos.

Comment: Check if you requested permissions from user to access gallery before trying to get files (assets).

Comment: No permissions requested here I tested it, its work right for iPhone but when run on iPad this issue appear.

Comment: You are trying to forcefully run your iPhone application in to iPad simulator, so kindly use a universal app and then run into the iPad. I have checked and its working fine.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but are we have anyway to solve this issue.

Comment: same problem on iPad3 iOS 9.3.3

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it changing the conde from ELCAssetCell.m

in setAssets function chage:

```
if (i < [_imageViewArray count]) {
        UIImageView *imageView = [_imageViewArray objectAtIndex:i];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.asset.thumbnail];
    }
```

to

```
if (i < [_imageViewArray count]) {
        UIImageView *imageView = [_imageViewArray objectAtIndex:i];
        //changed code:
        CGImageRef r1 = asset.asset.thumbnail;
        CGImageRef r2 = asset.asset.aspectRatioThumbnail;
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:r1 == nil?r2:r1];
    }
```

it will work until is fixed, always have in mind you have changed that line so check it on updates.

Hope that helps